# How to run a cronjob Monday, Wednesday and Friday for a specific time on Google Cloud Scheduler?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron

My current cronjob is not setup to run Monday, Wednesday and Friday, so I would like to know how can I do that and for a specific time?

Here is the current one:

```
00 08 * * *
```

This is the frequency that I currently have.

[Check here the screenshot of the current cronjob!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP0O2.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below cron for setup to run Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

`00 08 * * 1,3,5`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

How can I set this to run Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 9AM?

Comment: Please use below cron for setup to run Monday, Wednesday and Friday at 09:00AM.

00 09 * * 1,3,5

Comment: Thank You! God bless.

Comment: Most welcome!! If it's helpful for you so please vote me up☺️